# What does the word `scholar' convey when it is a part of a degree name?

Tags: graduate-admissions, degree

What does the word 'scholar' convey when it is a part of a degree name? Suppose that the graduate admission committee looks at an applicant who has completed a bachelor of engineering (scholar), how do they view the word `scholar' in this context?

Comment: Semi-tongue in cheek answer: I would view it as signifying that the applicant attended a rather pretentious institution, and probably little else.

Comment: It doesn't convey anything at all to me; I've never seen this used in US academia.  I'd have to look up the institution that awarded the degree and read their policies to find out what this designation means and what criteria are used in granting it.  Then I might have some clue how to view it.  I expect admissions committees would have to do the same, if they cared to take the trouble; otherwise they'd probably just ignore it.

Comment: If you are an applicant whose degree has this designation, and it actually means something significant, I think you should include an explanation with your application materials.  I would not count on it being properly understood otherwise.

Comment: At least at Trinity College Dublin, Ireland, having the designation "Scholar" means having achieved the highest grade in the Foundation Scholarship exams which are yearly exams for second years. Achieving the Scholar title means the university will waive all fees and provide you with free campus accommodation and a small stipend for five years. It is a very high academic achievement. https://www.tcd.ie/academicregistry/exams/scholarship/

Comment: As ryanp notes, I think this will be largely an international question, and if an applicant is applying outside of their home region (where the meaning is common knowledge, if it is) then they would want to explain it in their statement, or that one of their letter writers would explain the significance of the achievement (if it does have special meaning for the student).